# How many elements are there between two iterators

Tags: c++, stl

What's the best way to count all elements in an iterator?

I want code equivalent to this

```
template<typename T,typename S,S val>
struct ConstantFunctor : unary_function<T,S>
{S operator()(const T&) const {return val;}};
template<typename T>
struct TrueFunctor : ConstantFunctor<T,bool,true>{};
...
count_if(c.begin(),c.end(),TrueFunctor());
```

What's the best way to do that?

I can use `boost::lambda::constant(true)`, but maybe there's something clearer.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::distance`?

Comment: @Vinzenz That's what I was looking for... Thaks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to count all elements in a range. then you can use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), from the [`<iterator>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) header, like so:

```
int count = std::distance(begin(c), end(c));
```

It should be enough.

The [online doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) says about `std::distance`:

> Calculates the number of elements between first and last.

Comment: @davidhigh: This is 2015, and C++14 is released, so C++'s default meaning should be C++14, unless otherwise version is mentioned.